generator of a semigroup properties $A$ and $A-\alpha I$
at the moment I'm understanding a proof of a theorem about generating a C0-semigroup. Here's the theorem and the proof with associated definitions to understand it (see below).
My question is what Hille-Yosida has shown that the operator $E_{1}^{-1}\tilde{A}_{1}$ generates a C0-semigroup. I don't understand why the author of the article directly deduces the thesis from the evidence. i.e $E_{1}^{-1}A_{1}$ generate a C0-semigroup.
This would mean that, by definition of $\tilde{A}$, the operator $E_{1}^{-1}\tilde{A}_{1} = E_1^{-1}A-\alpha I$ which generates a C0-semigroup implies that $E_1^{-1}A$ generates a C0-semigroup. Is there a property that can do this?
In other words, is there a property like: if $A-\alpha I$ generates a C0-semigroup then $A$ generates a C0-semigroup?


I think I have shown that A generates a C0-semigroup,
by taking $T(t)=e^{\alpha t}S(t)$ where S(t) is the C0-semigroupe of $A-\alpha I$
